Docker container works fine locally, but gives error when trying to run on Azure
Brief Overview

I have a docker image that runs perfectly fine on my local device (macOS 14.3.1), but when I try to run the exact same image on azure container apps, it throws an exception.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated 

Background:

I have a docker image for an open source geo-coder photon, which runs perfectly fine locally.
The image can be found here: Photon docker

Docker run command: docker run -d -p 2322:2322 -v "$(pwd)/data:/photon/photon_data" --name photon sunraj751/photon-geocoder:latest



Problem:

The problem occurs when I try to run the same image on Azure Container apps.

For some reason it keeps throwing an exception stating IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING].


This is bit frustrating and confusing at the same time as I am running exactly the same docker image which is working on my local system (macOS 14.3.1).

Setup on Azure:

Azure File share for persistent storage, where the data is in fact getting downloaded.

This is then mounted to /photon/photon_data using app.yml


Azure Container is at max config 4 CPUs, 8gb Memory.
Below is a detailed error log from Log Stream:

2024-03-30 03:04:23,618 [main] INFO  de.komoot.photon.elasticsearch.Server - Started elastic search node
2024-03-30 03:04:23,618 [main] INFO  de.komoot.photon.App - Make sure that the ES cluster is ready, this might take some time.
2024-03-30 03:04:53,623 [main] INFO  de.komoot.photon.App - ES cluster is now ready.
Exception in thread "main" NoShardAvailableActionException[No shard available for [get [photon][place][DATABASE_PROPERTIES]: routing [null]]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[Xlitte1][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/get[s]]]; nested: IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when shard state is one of [POST_RECOVERY, STARTED, RELOCATED]];
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.perform(TransportSingleShardAction.java:209)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.onFailure(TransportSingleShardAction.java:196)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.access$1300(TransportSingleShardAction.java:123)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.handleException(TransportSingleShardAction.java:252)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1085)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1189)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1167)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.onFailure(TransportService.java:673)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.onFailure(ThreadContext.java:660)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:39)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: RemoteTransportException[[Xlitte1][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/get[s]]]; nested: IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when shard state is one of [POST_RECOVERY, STARTED, RELOCATED]];
Caused by: [photon/Ml54BOAPQKuEex9CRZpVww][[photon][0]] IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when shard state is one of [POST_RECOVERY, STARTED, RELOCATED]]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.readAllowed(IndexShard.java:1104)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.get(IndexShard.java:615)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.innerGet(ShardGetService.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.get.ShardGetService.get(ShardGetService.java:82)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.get.TransportGetAction.shardOperation(TransportGetAction.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.get.TransportGetAction.shardOperation(TransportGetAction.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportSingleShardAction.java:294)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportSingleShardAction.java:287)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:662)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:675)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Additional Info:

Docker File

FROM openjdk:11-jre

# Install pbzip2 for parallel extraction
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install \
        pbzip2 \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /photon
ADD https://github.com/komoot/photon/releases/download/0.5.0/photon-0.5.0.jar /photon/photon.jar
COPY entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh

# Make sure the script is executable
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

# Bind external storage to this location 
VOLUME /photon/photon_data
EXPOSE 2322

ENTRYPOINT /photon/entrypoint.sh


Entrypoint.sh (mentioned in docker file)

The data is downloaded from this link (around 4gigs of zipped file): http://download1.graphhopper.com/public/extracts/by-country-code/ca/



#!/bin/bash

# Download elasticsearch index
if [ ! -d "/photon/photon_data/elasticsearch" ]; then
    echo "Downloading search index"

    # Let graphhopper know where the traffic is coming from
    USER_AGENT="docker: sunraj751/photon-geocoder"
    # If you want to install a specific region only, enable the line below and disable the current 'wget' row.
    # Take a look at http://download1.graphhopper.com/public/extracts/by-country-code for your country
    wget --user-agent="$USER_AGENT" -O - http://download1.graphhopper.com/public/extracts/by-country-code/ca/photon-db-ca-latest.tar.bz2 | bzip2 -cd | tar x
fi

# Start photon if elastic index exists
if [ -d "/photon/photon_data/elasticsearch" ]; then
    echo "Start photon"
    java -jar photon.jar $@
else
    echo "Could not start photon, the search index could not be found"
fi


App.yaml (Container app config)

id: /subscriptions/BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-BLAH/photon-container-app
identity:
  type: None
location: Canada East
name: photon-container-app
properties:
  configuration:
    activeRevisionsMode: Single
    dapr: null
    ingress:
      additionalPortMappings: null
      allowInsecure: false
      clientCertificateMode: null
      corsPolicy: null
      customDomains: null
      exposedPort: 0
      external: true
      fqdn: photon-container-app.BLAH-BLAH-BLAH.azurecontainerapps.io
      ipSecurityRestrictions: null
      stickySessions: null
      targetPort: 80
      targetPortHttpScheme: null
      traffic:
      - latestRevision: true
        weight: 100
      transport: Auto
    maxInactiveRevisions: 100
    registries: null
    secrets: null
    service: null
  customDomainVerificationId: BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-BLAH
  delegatedIdentities: []
  environmentId: /subscriptions/BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-group/providers/photon-storage-environment
  eventStreamEndpoint: https://BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-BLAH/containerApps/photon-container-app/eventstream
  latestReadyRevisionName: photon-container-app--BLAH-BLAH
  latestRevisionFqdn: photon-container-app-BLAH-BLAH.canadaeast.azurecontainerapps.io
  latestRevisionName: photon-container-app-BLAH-BLAH
  managedEnvironmentId: /subscriptions/BLAH-BLAH/BLAH-BLAH/photon-storage-environment
  outboundIpAddresses:
  - xy.xyz.abc.cde
  - xy.xyz.abc.cde
  - xy.xyz.abc.cde
  provisioningState: Succeeded
  runningStatus: Running
  template:
    volumes:
    - name: photonazurefilevolume
      storageName: photonstoragemount
      storageType: AzureFile
    containers:
    - image: sunraj751/photon-docker:latest
      name: photon-container-app
      volumeMounts:
      - volumeName: photonazurefilevolume
        mountPath: /photon/photon_data
      resources:
        cpu: 4
        ephemeralStorage: 2Gi
        memory: 8Gi
    initContainers: null
    revisionSuffix: ''
    scale:
      maxReplicas: 2
      minReplicas: 1
      rules: null
    serviceBinds: null
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: null
  workloadProfileName: Consumption
resourceGroup: photon-container-apps-group
systemData:
  createdAt: '2024-03-29T20:12:29.3143267'
  createdBy: BLAH
  createdByType: BLAH
  lastModifiedAt: '2024-03-29T20:12:29.3143267'
  lastModifiedBy: BLAH
  lastModifiedByType: User
type: Microsoft.App/containerApps


Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  A link to your repository is helpful, but generally details like the image's Dockerfile or instructions to run the container on Azure need to be included directly in the question.  The error message suggests an Elasticsearch shard is RECOVERING and can't be used temporarily.

@DavidMaze, added some additional file content to the post, as for the docker run command on Azure Container Apps, I just hit start container after it's done uploading.
As for the recovering error message, this doesn't happen when I am running the docker locally, so not sure why would such thing happen while running on azure.
